# Interview : How to search for the first occurence of a character in a string efficiently?

Tags: hash

An interviewer of mine, asked me how to search for the first occurrence of a character in a string, efficiently.

I said use hashing, but he wanted a memory efficient way of handling it. Sorting the string and performing a binary search is out of the question, since the indices would be lost.

The interviewer didn't appear satisfied with my answer. Is there anything else I could've said?

Comment: Since the number of unique characters is typically small, a dictionary containing the unique characters as key, and their first position as value would seem memory efficient. The answer though, depends on the unstated requirements. If you just need to find the first occurrence of a character one time, just linearly searching the string would be most efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just search for the first occurence using a pointer. That's the most efficient way of finding(just 4 or 8 bytes of data needed).

```
unsigned long findIndex(char ch){
  char *str = "some really long; string; here";
  char *ptr = str;
  while(*ptr != ch || *ptr != '\0'){
     ptr++;
  }
  return (unsigned long)(ptr - str)
}
```

Basic law of computing science: You can either optimize for space or optimize for running time.

Basic law of software engineering: *BEEP* what the "computer scientists" say, find the sweet middle spot.